# Why is there a 'な' before ’ので’ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

このバックパックはよさそう**な**ので、買うつもりです。

'Because this backpack looks good, I intend to buy it.'

Following ~sou there is a 'na' placed before the 'node'. Why is this the case? Is it because of the ~sou implemented in the sentence? Furthermore, would the sentence still be grammatically correct even if the 'na' was not there?

Answer (score 2):

> 「このバックパックはよさそう**な**ので、買{か}うつもりです。」

「ので」 can only attach to the 連体形{れんたいけい} ("attributive form") of a conjugated word.  It simply cannot attach to any other conjugated form by "rules".

「そう**な**」 is the 連体形 of the auxiliary verb 「そう**だ**」; therefore, that is the ***only*** correct form that can directly precede 「ので」.

Thus, you ***cannot*** ever say 「そう**だ**ので」、「そう**だろ**ので」、「そう**で**ので」、「そう**に**ので」 or 「そう**なら**ので」.

> Furthermore, would the sentence still be grammatically correct even if the 'na' was not there?

No, it never would.  「そうので」 is simply ungrammatical because, as I stated above, 「そう」 is not the 連体形　of a word.

Comment: How about 「そうで」? I think that might be grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you know the meaning of ので and what nominals and the extended predicate  are.

よさそう is a nominal (名詞、な形容詞、etc.). All nominals take な before the の of the extended predicate (e.g. それなんです、分かるんだよ、高いんです）.

ので actually uses the の of the extended predicate (combined with で、which here is not the particle but rather is the gerund of the copula だ・です).

In short, the rule is nominal+な+extended predicate.